# RN callback when a Modal has been dismissed for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, modalviewcontroller

I'm using the React Native component `Modal` in my application. I would need a callback when the modal has been dismissed (like the native iOS completion block/closure). Looking at the documentation, I wasn't able to find anything about it, but probably I'm missing something.

Comment: I think you should just put it wherever the function is that's closing the modal.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to fire your callback on `Modal` `componentWillUnmount` and it will be fired right after the modal closes. Unfortunately the modal API is not `Promise` based, even if it should be, so this is the only way I found to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Probably I'm doing something wrong, but I receive that callback when the modal is not dismissed yet. I'm double checking if I failed something :)

Answer (score -1):

As of React-Native 0.45 there is no call back property on Modal component to hear when it is closed.

BTW Modal component is a controlled one, controlled by the visible property

```
visible={this.state.modalVisible} //boolean
```

you can use this state variable to update changes when modalVisible=false, that is when Modal is getting closed.

You can also approximately calculate the Modal exit animation time and use a Timeout function after modalVisible becomes false to bring any changes.

Note: In android the general trend is to close the Modal on physical back button press, hence u need to also handle 'onRequestClose' property of the Modal(where you can handle your call back updates).

Check [React-Native Modal Docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.45/docs/modal.html#modal)